# overall energy transformation as a diver moves downwards through water

Tags: energy-conservation, potential-energy

What is the answer to the following MCQ?

> A swimmer dives into a very deep pool at high speed. He slows down as
>   he moves towards the  bottom of the pool.  What is the overall energy
>   transformation as the diver moves downwards through the water?
>
> **A)** gravitational potential energy → kinetic energy + thermal energy (heat)
>
> **B)** gravitational potential energy → kinetic energy → thermal energy (heat)
>
> **C)** kinetic energy + gravitational potential energy → thermal energy (heat)
>
> **D)** kinetic energy → gravitational potential energy + thermal energy (heat)

Answer (score 1):

The **best** choice will be **C**, although it doesn't consider the energy stored in his body. The diver at the first moment has kinetic energy+gravitational potential energy and when trying to go deeper uses his potential energy in his muscles, and at the end all of this energies will be converted to heat.